# OnDrop function is not being called despite everything being set up correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement very basic drag and drop functionality to a Unity project and I am suprised to find that the OnDrop function is never called.

I have a very simple script for the drop event on a GameObject:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
 
public class Socket : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler
{
    public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Drop registered");
    }
}
```

and a fairly simple script for a drag GameObject:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
 
public class DragDrop : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IEndDragHandler, IDragHandler
{
    private RectTransform rectTransform;
    private CanvasGroup canvasGroup;
    private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
   
    public Sprite initial;
    public Sprite onDrag;
 
    private void Awake()
    {
        rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        canvasGroup = GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
        spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
 
        spriteRenderer.sprite = initial;
    }
 
    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = onDrag;
        canvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = false;
    }
 
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        rectTransform.anchoredPosition = rectTransform.anchoredPosition + eventData.delta;
    }
    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        spriteRenderer.sprite = initial;
        canvasGroup.blocksRaycasts = true;
    }
 
}
```

OnDrop just **does not work. ** It is never called.

- 2d collision is set up
- raytracer is set up
- Drag events tested on target GameObject with 'socket script', they work.
- Z level has been played with to no effect.

Comment: Try commenting out the `blocksRaycasts` line, or set a different value to see if it changes the behaviour.

Comment: Just went through and tried every possible state of blocksRaycast from each GameObject, no effect.

Comment: drop target requires a graphic for it to work, does the target have a graphic?  see [drop handler](https://forum.unity.com/threads/drag-drop-system-idrophandler-event-not-called.264475/)

Comment: The 'socket'/ drop target GameObject and the 'DragDrop' GameObject each have a Sprite Renderer, 2d Circle Collider, Transform Rect, and Canvas Group. The Camera has a Physics 2d Raycaster and the Canvas has a Graphic Raycaster. The drop target can detect other events but nothing though the DragDrop GameObject.

Comment: What other events are you referring to?  You seem to be mixing up UI and 2d.  Pretty sure drag/drop only works for UI.  As i mentioned before, the drop target needs a graphic on it, anything that inherits from [Graphic](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic.html)

Comment: PointerEventData. The drop target has a sprite. The drop target detects events, but the raycaster will not make it through the dragged object no matter what setting or variable is changed. I've even tried with OnPointerUp and the raytracing will not make it through the dragged object. All other events are confirmed working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have mixed both 2D and UI technologies together.  Im not quite sure how your setup is suppose to work, but this is definitely causing some confusion and problems.  I suggest reading more in depth about these separate technologies to understand their purpose and use cases.  I will do a quick summary here.

Canvas is used for UI elements, components such as Text, Image, Button, Slider, etc.  These use the RectTransform component, and exist on the UI layer, and are rendered by the Canvas component.  These objects need to be parented to a Canvas to be rendered.

Sprite Renderers are used for 2D objects.  These are rendered from the SpriteRenderer, not the Canvas.  These behave in the same way that the 3d objects do, with the MeshRenderer replaced by the SpriteRenderer.  They use the Transform component, and are interacted with in the same way 3d objects are, except they use their respective 2D counterparts for components and functions.  eg. OnTriggerEnter2D, BoxCollider2D, etc.

To use the 2d approach, make the following changes:

Create a gameobject with a BoxCollider2D component, scale it to fill the game scene (or parent to camera if applicable).  This is the background used for the raycasts.  Set isTrigger to true if the collision is a problem, or adjust 2d collision matrix.

Both the drag item and drop target should have the following components:
Transform, Collider2D (any 2D collider), SpriteRenderer

Camera requires the Physics 2D Raycaster.

Drag n Drop Item Script:

```
private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
private Collider2D collider2d;

public Sprite initialSprite;
public Sprite draggingSprite;

private void Awake()
{
    spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    collider2d = GetComponent<Collider2D>();

    spriteRenderer.sprite = initialSprite;
}

public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    collider2d.enabled = false;
    spriteRenderer.sprite = draggingSprite;
}
public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    transform.position = eventData.pointerCurrentRaycast.worldPosition;
}
public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    collider2d.enabled = true;
    spriteRenderer.sprite = initialSprite;
}
```

The event system is casting a ray that hits a collider in the scene.  When dragging, the ray should be hitting the background collider which allows us to position the object at the hit point (through pointerCurrentRaycast.worldPosition).  We disable the drag objects collider when dragging, otherwise the ray will not hit the drop target collider when released.

No changes were made to the drop target script shown in the question.

I suggest testing this in a fresh scene first, and do some experimenting.
Below is an image of the objects I used to test this, and the hierarchy.

[image: Setup]

-Cheers